# I keep getting the error missing \begin{document}. \ProcessOptionsKV[p]{Gm} even tho its not missing idk what to do pls help

Tags: errors, missing, document

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{algorithm, algorithmicx, algpseudocode}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}


\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm; left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definitia}
\renewcommand{\proofname}{Demonstratie}


\title{\bf Primul meu document in \LaTeX{}} 

\author{Nume Prenume}

\date{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
        Acesta este primul meu document scris in \LaTeX{}
    \end{abstract}
    
    \section{Introducere}
    
    In continuarea vom argumenta de ce \LaTeX{} este indicat pentru redactarea textelor si a formulelor matematice
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item este un program stabil pe diverse platforme;
        \item aduce noi imbunatatiri in ce priveste calitatea si usurinta de redactare
    \end{itemize}
    
    \section{Cum scriem text matematic in \LaTeX}
    
    Textul matematic se introduce prin inserarea unui dolar in ambele capete astfel: $(\cos x+i\sin x)^{n}=\cos{nx}+i\sin {nx}.$
    
    Daca se doreste afisarea ecuatiei pe urmatorul rand centrata se foloseste dublu dolar in ambele capete astfel: $$ \int f(x)g'(x)dx=f(x)g(x)-\int f'(x)g(x)dx.$$
    Numerotam urmatoarele formule folosind mediul:
    \begin{align}
        a^2-b^2=& (a+b)(a-b)\label{eq1}\\
        a^3+b^3=& (a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)\label{eq2} \\
        a^3-b^3=& (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)\label{eq3}
    \end{align}
    
    Ne referim la una dintre formulele de mai sus astfel: din formula \eqref{eq1} rezulta \ldots sau din formula \eqref{eq2} rezult\u a \ldots
    
    Avem urmatoarele definitii:
    \begin{defn}\label{def1}
        Fie $G=(X, U)$ care contine cel putin un ciclu hamiltonian se numeste \textbf{lant(ciclu) hamiltonian}.
    \end{defn}
    
    \begin{defn}\label{def2}
        Un graf $G=(X, U)$ care contine cel putin un ciclu hamiltonian se numeste \textbf{graf hamiltonian}.
    \end{defn}
    
    \begin{teorema}\label{teo1}
        Fie $G=(X, U)$ un graf neorientat in care $\vert X \vert = n \geq 3$ si pentru orice varf $x \in X$ avem $d(x) \geq \dfrac{n}{2}$. Atunci $G$ este graf hamiltanian.
    \end{teorema}
    \begin{proof}
        Cum fiecare $x \in X$ este conectat cu toate celelalte varfuri din $X$, rezulta ca graficul este complet, deci putem forma ciclul
        $C= [x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3},  x_{1}]$ care este un ciclu elementar care contine toate varfurile \ldots 
        In consecinta, graful este hamiltonian.
    \end{proof}
    
    Folosind Teorema \ref{teo1} putem obtine \ldots
    
    Dac\u a avem de recactat un algoritm simplu procedam astfel:
    
    \begin{algorithm}[htbp]
        \caption{}
        \label{alg1}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \If {$i\geq maxval$}
            \State $i\gets 0$
            \Else
            \If{$i+k\leq maxval$}
            \State $i\gets i+k$
            \EndIf
            \EndIf
            
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
    
    Din Algoritmul \ref{alg1} rezulta \ldots
    
    \section{Concluzii}
    
    Cu ajutorul unui numar mic de comenzi, usor de inteles putem realiza un document avand o calitate tipografica deosebita.
\end{document}
```

Comment: delete `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`

Comment: unrelated but `a^2-b^2=& ` should be `a^2-b^2&= ` or you get bad space around =

Comment: You should also add `\usepackage[romanian]{babel}`

Comment: Please don't vandalise posts, not even your own. Flagged for rolling-back.

Answer (score 1):

- You have error in code line:

```
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm; left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
```

In code `geometry` observe in options use of `;` , it is wrong and had to be replaced by comma!

- considering @David Carlisle comments, your MWE should be as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry} % shorter for \usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
    \newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}
    \newtheorem{defn}{Definitia}
    \renewcommand{\proofname}{Demonstratie}
\usepackage{algorithm, algorithmicx, algpseudocode}
\usepackage{indentfirst}


\title{Primul meu document in \LaTeX{}}
\author{Nume Prenume}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
    Acesta este primul meu document scris in \LaTeX{}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introducere}

In continuarea vom argumenta de ce \LaTeX{} este indicat pentru redactarea textelor si a formulelor matematice

\begin{itemize}
    \item este un program stabil pe diverse platforme;
    \item aduce noi imbunatatiri in ce priveste calitatea si usurinta de redactare
\end{itemize}

\section{Cum scriem text matematic in \LaTeX}

Textul matematic se introduce prin inserarea unui dolar in ambele capete astfel: $(\cos x+i\sin x)^{n}=\cos{nx}+i\sin {nx}.$

Daca se doreste afisarea ecuatiei pe urmatorul rand centrata se foloseste dublu dolar in ambele capete astfel: $$ \int f(x)g'(x)dx=f(x)g(x)-\int f'(x)g(x)dx.$$
Numerotam urmatoarele formule folosind mediul:
\begin{align}
    a^2-b^2 & = (a+b)(a-b)\label{eq1}\\
    a^3+b^3 & = (a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)\label{eq2} \\
    a^3-b^3 & = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)\label{eq3}
\end{align}

Ne referim la una dintre formulele de mai sus astfel: din formula \eqref{eq1} rezulta \ldots sau din formula \eqref{eq2} rezult\u a \ldots

Avem urmatoarele definitii:
\begin{defn}\label{def1}
    Fie $G=(X, U)$ care contine cel putin un ciclu hamiltonian se numeste \textbf{lant(ciclu) hamiltonian}.
\end{defn}

\begin{defn}\label{def2}
    Un graf $G=(X, U)$ care contine cel putin un ciclu hamiltonian se numeste \textbf{graf hamiltonian}.
\end{defn}

\begin{teorema}\label{teo1}
    Fie $G=(X, U)$ un graf neorientat in care $\vert X \vert = n \geq 3$ si pentru orice varf $x \in X$ avem $d(x) \geq \dfrac{n}{2}$. Atunci $G$ este graf hamiltanian.
\end{teorema}
\begin{proof}
    Cum fiecare $x \in X$ este conectat cu toate celelalte varfuri din $X$, rezulta ca graficul este complet, deci putem forma ciclul
    $C= [x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3},  x_{1}]$ care este un ciclu elementar care contine toate varfurile \ldots
    In consecinta, graful este hamiltonian.
\end{proof}

Folosind Teorema \ref{teo1} putem obtine \ldots

Dac\u a avem de recactat un algoritm simplu procedam astfel:

\begin{algorithm}[htbp]
    \caption{}
    \label{alg1}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \If {$i\geq maxval$}
        \State $i\gets 0$
        \Else
        \If{$i+k\leq maxval$}
        \State $i\gets i+k$
        \EndIf
        \EndIf

    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

Din Algoritmul \ref{alg1} rezulta \ldots

\section{Concluzii}

Cu ajutorul unui numar mic de comenzi, usor de inteles putem realiza un document avand o calitate tipografica deosebita.
\end{document}
```

[image]